# Javascript: Performance of 'closured' variables

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

Is this:

```
function Con () {
    var foo = 42;
    this.foo = foo
}
```

more slow than this:

```
function Con () {
    this.foo = 42;
}
```

On subsequent uses of the foo variable on an object returned by an invocation of the 'Con'-constructor?
Ie. does it hurt if the variable has first been living in the closure of the constructor invocation?

EDIT:
@FakeRainBrigand: Well, here you measure the time of constructing an object using the constructor. Right?
I was rather thinking about subsequent uses of a constructed object, like this:

```
var myObj = new Con();
var bar = myObj.foo;
```

What is the time usage of *the last line only* (that is, the accessing of the variable `foo`) in the two cases?

Comment: it is slower, but nothing that'll hurt your performance

Comment: They're not equivalent. In the first one you have two variables. If `foo` is not passed by reference (strings, numbers...) then `foo` and `this.foo` won't be in sync if you use `foo`. If you use `this.foo` then `var foo` doesn't help.

Comment: This is one of those cases where the calls are so negligible that you are better off using what is more friendly for code readability than making the optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slightly slower.  Here's a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/18328589).  It's more or less negligible, and there are nearly definitely other issues you should worry about.  We can do this 60 million times per second, so worry about the things you can only do a few times per second.

[image: performance test with code in original question]

---

I [changed the tests](http://jsperf.com/18328589/2) to not include actually making the constructor, and they became even more identical.  This is likely due to internal optimizations.  Here, the two fall into the margin of error.

[image: second performance test]

Comment: Well, here you measure the time of constructing an object using the constructor. Right?
I was rather thinking about subsequent uses of a constructed object, like this:

    var myObj = new Con();
    var bar = myObj.foo;

What is the time usage of *the latter statement only* (that is, the accessing of the variable `foo`) in the two cases?